# Nice binomial identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

After inspiring by Cardano method for $3th$ degree equations,
I noticed that it may be possible to express $(x+y)^n$ with only these terms: $x^n,y^n, xy,x+y $

Let's see some examples:

$(x+y)^1=x^1+y^1$

$(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2*(xy)$

$(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3*(xy) *(x+y)$ $-$ (Cardano method uses this equality)

$(x+y)^4=x^4+y^4+4*(xy) *(x+y)^2-2*(xy)^2$

$(x+y)^5=x^5+y^5+5*(xy)*(x+y)^3-5*(xy)^2*(x+y)$

$(x+y)^6=x^6+y^6+6*(xy)*(x+y)^4-9*(xy)^2*(x+y)^2+2*(xy)^3$

$(x+y)^7=x^7+y^7+7*(xy)*(x+y)^5-14*(xy)^2*(x+y)^3+7*(xy)^3*(x+y)$

...

So I decided to generalize these formulas and came up with this formula:

$$(x+y)^n=x^n+y^n+\sum_{i=0; 2i<=n-2}^{} {(-1)^i*H_n^i*(xy)^{1+i}*(x+y)^{n-2-2i}}$$

Here $H_n^i$ are positive numbers depending on $n$ and $i$

I only found some small values of it such that:

$$H_n^0=n$$

$$H_n^1=\frac{n*(n-3)}{2}$$

I would like to ask:

1. Can we prove that it is true for all $n$ and find formula for $H_n^i$
2. Any similar formula for 3 or more terms like : $(x+y+z)^n$

Comment: You will be interested to learn about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: [Fundamental theorem on symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials).

Comment: Compare https://oeis.org/A034807

Comment: Nice, we found similar post with a proof and a formula for numbers inside it. Welcome anyone having any reference/idea/related post for the 3+ terms case